# Can Charles proxy compose an HTTP request from scratch?

Tags: http, request, fiddler, charles-proxy

I've been searching for the solution, and perhaps I'm overtired and missed the solution.

How does a person manually compose an HTTP GET or POST request using Charles Proxy?

Like the feature in Fiddler, I'm looking for the ability to manually open an editor and enter the body and headers of the request.  That's the primary interest I have in Charles.

The ability to capture and edit and execute live requests is almost the same, but I have data captured outside of Charles, and want to use those headers+query+body.

Searching SO and the web has lead to no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in Charles you have to use the Repeat Tool and the Edit Tool in combination, rather than a single tool. (http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/edit/)

There are other options if you're running on Mac and can't use Fiddler, e.g. http://www.wiztools.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks.  You're right, that repeat tool is mostly the same but without having the context, just thinking of starting up Charles and firing a pre-assembled request, leaves me wanting.  The wiztools REST client looks promising, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

As of version 3.11, Charles Proxy has a Compose feature (Edit --> Compose or cmd-m).  It's still not as great as Fiddler, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out the "Compose" feature, but the Charles Proxy website doesn't appear to have any documentation on it. For a stylesheet on my computer, would I `GET > ../desktop/style.css`? Or would it be a query, header, etc...?

Comment: I don't see this feature documented on Charles Proxy's site either, but they did mention it in the release notes for version 3.11: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/.  The compose feature will make an HTTP request to any endpoint that's available on your computer (external or internal).  If you don't have a server running and you're on a Mac, you can set up a server easily by running this in your terminal where your stylesheet is: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000  .  Then you can access your stylesheet at http://localhost:8000/style.css from Charles or from your browser.

Comment: I have Charles 3.11.5 and cmd-m does work, however there is no Compose in the Edit menu...was that part a mistake?  If so I would remove that part of your answer.

Comment: @levininja The feature was introduced version 3.11.  You can refer to the release notes here: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/.  Specifically, `Compose – create requests from scratch in Charles`.